# how to order the results of a `describe ` statement in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, describe

I want to be able to order the column names when I do a `describe` statement in SQL:

```
use <db_name>;
describe <table_name>;
```

What do I order it by?

```
use <db_name>;
describe <table_name> order by <????>;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related, if it's of interest, I wrote a *Describe All Tables* in [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679580). One could modify it to do whatever ordering. Plus, as stated, it gets all tables.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (easily) do this directly with MySQL, however, you can get the result with a simple shell wrapper:

`mysql --e 'describe <table_name_goes_here>' --batch | sort -k 1`